# Does $1093^2$ divide $2^{1093}-2$?

Tags: number-theory

Does $1093^2$ divide $2^{1093}-2$?

Can anyone help? I used Euler's theorem but it doesn't give any results.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wieferich_prime

Comment: @labbhattacharjee, I looked at this link. But can you give a link to proof of this fact?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee, This problem is solving only by computation?

Comment: @RFZ 1093 is one of the two Weiferich primes known until now (the other is 3511). By definition, a Weiferich prime $p$ is such that $p^2\mid(2^{p-1}-1)$, so it also divides $2^{p}-2 = 2(2^{p-1}-1)$.

Comment: This type of proof must be given by explicite computation. One can simplify a bit doing the exponent at 2 to 1092/3=364 such that $2^{364}-1 == 0 \pmod {1093^2}$

Comment: (... additional comment to the previous one:) for me it was also an exciting experience to arrive at generalizations such like the problem of "Fermat-quotients"; I made an essay on it(http://go.helms-net.de/math/expdioph/fermatquotients.pdf) and perhaps it awakes some couriosity in you too.